# @ConditionalOnProperty default bean work not currectly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 beans:

```
@Component("CryptoClient")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "enabled-client", havingValue = "AfsClient")
public class AfsClient implements CryptoClient {
```

and

```
@Component("CryptoClient")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "enabled-client", havingValue = "JinnClient")
public class JinnClient implements CryptoClient {
```

I change property value:

`enabled-client: AfsClient` or `enabled-client: JinnClient` and use this bean. But now I add default bean(if `enabled-client` property does not exist):

```
    @Bean("CryptoClient")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "enabled-client", matchIfMissing = true)
    public CryptoClient defaultClient(EDSService edsService) {
        return new AfsClient(edsService);
    }
```

If `enabled-client` property does not exist - it works fine. But it works even when property exists. Called anyway default bean.

Answer (score 6):

Let's first understand **matchIfMissing** property :  It is used to specify the default processing when the corresponding property is not configured in the configuration file.

By default, **matchIfMissing** is false, that means, if the property is not configured, the automatic configuration does not take effect and bean is not created.
If **matchIfMissing is true**, it means that if there is no corresponding property configuration, the automatic configuration takes effect by default and bean (*defaultClient in this case*) is created and if corresponding property configuration exist - obviously It will create the bean. :)

so if **matchIfMissing** is set to **true** - in any case bean **defaultClient** will be created.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your default client is also a AfsClient. So complete the first bean definition with the following:

```
@Component("CryptoClient")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "enabled-client", havingValue = "AfsClient", matchIfMissing = true)
public class AfsClient implements CryptoClient {
```

This bean will be created if the given property matches OR if it's missing.